# How to draw selected text

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a custom replacement for the Textbox/Label controls. It needs to provide similar functionality but will be optimized and (hopefully) much quicker in the context of my application. It needs to be able to support multi-line text selection. I'm wondering if there is a simple way to draw selected text? Right now it looks like the only way might be to calculate where the selection rectangle should be drawn and draw it manually. I was hoping to get recommendations on the easiest way to accomplish this or any alternative methods. Thanks.

Comment: There's no way any custom UserControl that you create for this purpose will be faster than the built-in controls.  If you're actually running into performance problems with Textboxes and Labels, chances are you have way too many of them on your form.

Comment: I wouldn't say there's no way, it just seems like it would be very difficult to achieve which is why I recommended looking at other 3rd party controls since companies that have based their existence on that are much more likely to have found room for improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer`.

Just override methods from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), ForeColor);
}

public override Size GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)
{
    return TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text, Font);
}
```

Of course, you'll need to handle a couple more events such as `OnFontChanged` or `OnSizeChanged` if you need custom behavior implemented.

If what you are looking for is targeting specific text (selected text) in those controls, you might want to take a look at this [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20131130031200/http://www.codedblog.com/2007/09/17/owner-drawing-a-windowsforms-textbox/). Source code of a spell-checking library(SharpSpell) is also linked from this article.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting basic controls for an application is a major task and shouldn't be done unless as an absolute last resort (IMO). If the included controls aren't meeting your exceptations I would recommend purchasing a 3rd party control library that has their business built around designing and supporting these controls. I've had alot of success using [Telerik's](http://www.telerik.com) ASP.NET controls I've seen many positive statements about their other lines of controls.

There's also many other sources of 3rd party controls you could look into.